# Package to generate n-gram language models with smoothing? (Alternatives to NLTK)

Tags: nlp, nltk, n-gram

I'd like to find some type of package or module (preferably Python or Perl, but others would do) that automatically generate n-gram probabilities from an input text, and can automatically apply one or more smoothing algorithms as well.

That is, I am looking for something like the NLTK `NgramModel` class. I can't use this for my purposes because there are some bugs with the smoothing functions which make it choke when you ask for the probability of a word it hasn't seen before.

I've read through the dev forums for NLTK and as of now there seems to be no progress on this.

Any alternatives out there?

Comment: Hi there! How did you calculate the perplexity? Which toolkit or package was useful for you? I am stuck with the same problem now :( Not able to use nltk to calculate the perplexity.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I answered my own question, so I'll mention what I've found here in case others are looking for it.

There are two toolkits that I've found:

- [SRILM](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/)
- [The CMU-Cambridge Statistical Language Modeling Toolkit](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/SLM/toolkit.html)

They appear to have very similar functionality. Both include a variety of smoothing functions.

Answer (score 0):

NLTK also provides an ngram model package, which has smoothing, backoff, etc.

Answer (score -2):

I guess another answer would be to either download the [datasets Google provides](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) if that data is suitable for your application, or maybe use their [online viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams).